# VNC Viewer: Timed out waiting for a response from the host computer

Tags: vmware, vnc, osx-el-capitan

I have VNC Server installed on my OS X 10.11 El Capitan as virtual machine on my VMware Workstation 12 Pro running on Windows Server 2012 R2.

But when i try to connect to it with VNC Viewer, it says:
**Timed out waiting for a response from the host computer**
I also tried forwarding the ports in the NAT configuration file.

```
[incomingtcp]
# Use these with care - anyone can enter into your virtual machine throughthese...

# FTP (both active and passive FTP is always enabled)
#      ftp localhost 8887
#8887 = 192.168.27.128:21
5900 = 192.168.110.2:5900

# WEB (make sure that if you are using named webhosting, names point to
#     your host, not to guest... And if you are forwarding port other
#     than 80 make sure that your server copes with mismatched port 
#     number in Host: header)
#      lynx http://localhost:8888
#8888 = 192.168.27.128:80

# SSH
#      ssh -p 8889 root@localhost
#8889 = 192.168.27.128:22

[incomingudp]
# UDP port forwarding example
#6000 = 192.168.27.128:6001
5900 = 192.168.110.2:5900
```

Do i configured the ports wrong?
Please help!